# Saving html table values

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, html-table

I am new to webpage design and I was wondering if I could get some piece of advice.

I have created a table using HTML that has 2 columns and "N" number of rows say 10. I want the first column to hold time values while the second to hold comments. For now I want both the time and comment values for the rows to be input by the user and saved into a database as soon as they are entered.

I thought about putting text boxes inside each cell of the table and trying to save the data that way but not all cells will be filled for a bigger table.

What would be the best way to save the table values into a database.

Comment: There are to many questions in your text. What have you tried so far? What do you mean by "best way to approach this" (approach what)?

Comment: your text box approach is only correct way.

Comment: I am trying to save each cell value of the table into a database. How do I do that. Do I use text boxes that act as cells to captures the values then store those in the database or is there a better way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for you requirement you will need to use a `Grid` which will handle most of the things for you.

Have a look at [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Comment: @hadoken if you are using `php` then this grid has lots of examples/demos. You can accept the answer if it helped you.